# Adding an xml to java classpath in UNIX

Tags: java, unix, classpath

We know that we use the below for setting classpath for java execution from UNIX. This will work for ading all the jar files to classpath.

```
java -cp ..jars/* MainClass
```

But if I want to add an xml file to classpath, what should I do?
I tried the below and it is not working.

```
java -cp ..jars/*:../resources/abc.xml MainClass
```

In eclipse, to do the same thing, I just have to right click the resources folder and select "Use as Source Folder".

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the xml file name to the classpath. Just add the path to the folder which holds the xml file. In your example: ../resources/